# In every set of 100 integers, there exist two whose difference is a multiple of 37.

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Could anyone explain how to prove this? There are 4950 ways in which a difference between two integers from the set can be taken. I cannot understand how to relate it with a multiple of 37.

Comment: Hint:  There are only $37$ possible remainders on division by $37$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your problem in the body of the question, instead of putting only in the title.

Comment: Sorry I'm quite unfamiliar with the platform

Comment: Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every integer in the set, take the remainder of the division by 37: there are only 37 possibile different results. Let $a$ and $b$ two integers of the set which have the same remainder, i.e:

$$
\begin{align*}
a &= r + 37h,\\
b &= r + 37k.
\end{align*}
$$

Now consider the difference $a - b = 37(h-k)$: it is a multiple of 37.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found out where I was thinking wrong.